# Select drop down "selected "option not getting highlighted

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, browser

I'm using Spring MVC and setting the list of counties to the request.
I set the list to the page request but the "selected" option is not getting highlighted on the HTML page.

My Controller code is as follows:

`//Populate drop down selection with list of counties
ArrayList<County> counties = countyInformation.getCounties(State, Zip);
request.setAttribute("counties", counties);`

My JSP code is as follows:

```
 <form:select class="form-control" path="counties">
        <form:option value="Select County"></form:option> 
        <form:options items="${countiesList}" itemValue="countyFipsId" itemLabel="countyName" /> 
 </form:select>
```

I have also tried this :

```
 <select id="county" name="county">
    <option value="">Select County</option>
     <c:forEach items="${counties}" var="county">

                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${county == selectedCountyId}">
                            <option value="${county.countyId}" selected="selected">${county.countyName}</option>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <option value="${county.countyId}" >${county.countyName}</option>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>

                </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

Is there any bug in the Spring / Browser rendering?
Currently, the selected option shows up in the dev toolbar, but the option itself is not highlighted. 
[It doesn't come into focus on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFJ9t.png)

Is there a jQuery / JavaScript equivalent solution for this?
Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute in the controller is set to `"counties"`, but your `form:options items` is set to `${countiesList}`.  Try changing it to `${counties}`.

You might also want to try wrapping your `form:select` block in a `spring:bind` tag.

```
<spring:bind path="controllerName.counties">
    <form:select class="form-control" path="controllerName.counties">
        <form:option value="Select County"></form:option> 
        <form:options items="${counties}" itemValue="countyFipsId" itemLabel="countyName" /> 
    </form:select>
</spring:bind>
```

EDIT:  After reading your post again, I'm not sure if my solution is what you're after.  Are you looking for the browser to recognize the selected list item after it is selected from the dropdown?  If that's the case, you'll have to add an onClick() handler via javascript in order to process the request.  The selected item won't be recognized until some kind of explicit action takes place (like a js function, a post, or a get).

Comment: Yes I noticed the error. my mistake when writing this down. But this solution did not work. I tried using the <spring:bind> too, no luck.

Comment: If you can click on the image mentioned in my question, you will get the idea. Basically I want the selected item to be highlighted when the page loads. The selected item in the drop down option is not being highlighted in the HTML page. And I am unable to control it from the controller end. Is there a onPageLoad JS equivalent solution for this?

Comment: Are you setting a session attribute for the selected item?